# Groovy 2.1.3 compilation failure in IDEA 12.1.1

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I'm getting a compilation failure in IDEA 12 when trying to compile a Gradle project with the Groovy plugin installed and using Groovy version 2.1.3. The error I'm getting in IDEA that I don't see on the command line is here:

https://gist.github.com/jbrisbin/5416187

I'm using `@CompileStatic` in extension classes, if that's helpful.

Any ideas on workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently when you create a new project in the latest versions of IDEA, the "external build" option is by default checked.

If you go into the settings and uncheck it [1], this error goes away (and the extremely excessive CPU usage goes away as well!).

Thanks to JetBrains support for the pointer.

[1] - http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3550/20121206235318.png